# Drawing the first Ace using Geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I came across the following question:

> What is the expected number of cards that need to be turned over in a regular 52-card deck in order to see the first ace?

The answer comes out to be $10.6$ with the following approach:

Define $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{48}$, such that $X_i = 1$ if the $i$th card turns over before four aces, $0$ otherwise. Thus, the total number of cards turned to see the first ace $= 1 + \sum X_i$ using linearity of expectation, $E(X) = 1 + \sum ( E(X_i))$.
Now consider the $i$th card and the four aces; all the orders are equally likely: X, A, A, A, A Or A, X, A, A, A, or three others. They are equally likely when we do not know the position of these Aces concerning the deck. Hence we have five equally likely slots for the ith card: 1 A 2 A 3 A 4 A 5. We are interested in 1st slot. Hence $E(X_i) = 1/5$ for all $i = 1$ to $48$.

Thus E(X) = 1 + 48/5 = 53/5 = 10.6

My question is, can we somehow model this with a geometric distribution approach?

Comment: Your solution is correct.  However, the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) requires Bernoulli trials, which you do not have in this case since the cards are drawn without replacement.  You would only have Bernoulli trials if you were drawing with replacement.

Comment: Your heading has "geometric distribution", but the question doesn't. It seems "geometric distribution" is your insertion ? The answr uses indicator random variables along with linearity of expectation

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Is it wrong to say an Ace and NOT an Ace as 2 Bernoulli events?

Comment: Again, to have Bernoulli trials, you would have to select *with* replacement.  Since you are selecting *without* replacement, the geometric distribution does not apply.

Comment: The thing that makes Bernoulli trials produce a geometric distribution is the fact that each Bernoulli trial is independent of all the others. If you were to put the selected card back in the deck and thoroughly reshuffle the deck after every card turned over, you would have a $48/52$ chance of no ace on the first draw, a $48/52$ chance of no ace on the second draw, and probability $(48\times48)/(52\times52)$ of no ace at all in the first two draws. But without the replacement and shuffling, the probability of no ace in the first two draws is $(48\times47)/(52\times51)$.